# Laravel Backpack Add/update pivot table value

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have these tables :

```
items

statistiques

item_statistique
```

I created a model and AdminController for `items` and `statistiques`.
So I wanted to add statistiques to my items in my admin panel, this is ok, but ....

In my `item_statistique` table, there is a 3 fields that i need to edit (`min`,`max` and `mandatory`).
Is there a field in backpack that I can use for this case ? It's common to have pivot fields to edit, it must be a way to do it but I didn't found it :(

Actually it looks like this :

[image]

But can't update pivot values for each statistiques :(

Answer (score 0):

in your Item model class place this relationship

```
public functions statistics(){
   $this->belongsToMany(Statistic::class)->withPivot(['min' , 'max' , 'mandatory']);
}
```

in your Statistic model class place this relationship

```
public functions items(){
   $this->belongsToMany(Item::class)
}
```

Then in your controller you can have this to update pivot values

```
 public function update($id){

    $item = Item::find($id);
    $statistic_id = 1;

   // to add

    $item->statistics()->attach($statistic_id, [
        'min' => 5,
        'max' => 10,
        'mandatory' => true
    ]);

    // to update
    $item->statistics()->updateExistingPivot($statistic_id, [
        'min' => 5,
        'max' => 10,
        'mandatory' => true
    ]);
  }
```